# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]' - Xcode 8.0 Swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, segue

I am creating a function that allows me to create a array on VC1 and then I can transfer over the array using "prepare for segue" to VC2. On VC2 I can append an item to the array in VC2 and then transfer over the array back to VC1. My issue is, is that on the line `if let newString = receivedString` (VC1) and erro is comming up that states, "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'"This is my code on VC1:

```
var receivedString = [String]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if let newString = receivedString {
        print(newString)
    }
}
```

This is my code on VC2:

```
let stringToPass = "Hello World"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
    destinationVC.receivedString = [stringToPass]
    destinationVC.receivedString.append("DYLAN MURPHY")
}
```

I am new to Swift so I realise that I may be completely wrong so I appreciate any help that leads me closer to this goal.

Comment: In `if let`, delete the word `let`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here – if you just want to print `receivedString` (that should really have a better name, as it's a `[String]`, not a `String`), then just say `print(receivedString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally do what you want to do a little bit differently. In VC1 I would add this code:

```
var username = [String]()
```

In VC2:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toSecondViewController" {

        let hello = segue.destination as! ViewController

        hello.username.append(textField.text!)




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that, since `receivedString` is not an optional type, the `if let` doesn't make sense.  You've created it as an array of strings and that's what it's always going to be.

Even if the array is empty, it will still evaluate as an array.

Comment: If I remove `let` then I haven't declared the variable so where would I need to declare it.

Comment: I'm not the one who told you to remove `let`; I'm the one telling you that testing for `nil` isn't reasonable for a non-optional variable.  :)